# GKE Helm Gitlab-CI image tag adding additional character ':'

Tags: gitlab-ci, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I'm completely lost on this one. I'm using gitlab ci to pipeline updates into a GKE cluster managed with helm. I have 2 namespaces for different environments on the cluster, 2 different pipelines in the gitlab-ci.yml for each corresponding branch. All worked fine until 2 days ago, the GKE cluster for 1 namespace keeps failing stating invalidImageName- ":aa8905b2" (the image gets name based on the short SHA from the commit during the ci pipeline).

First thought is, theres an extra semi-colon in the pipeline, but I've gone over it multiple times and there is not, I've even echoed the tag just before the helm upgrade command and verified that there is no additional : . From my local terminal, everything works fine, and GKE updates the deployments without issue. I even adjusted the deployment yaml templates to conditionally look for the : and replace it with "", which again works fine when tested from the terminal and intentionally adding a : to the image tag, but fails when done through the pipeline.

What else am I missing? Has anyone else come across something like this before? Again, only happens on one branch/namespace, both are set up exactly the same and currently share the exact same code on both branches.

To verify I'm not crazy...

The gitlab-ci.yml:

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

variables:
  DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG: ${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}
...
//build and deploy the dev/test branch is first, then script for build main branch, all using the same DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG, then the deploy for main branch:
Deploy-Helm:
  stage: deploy
  image: kiwigrid/gcloud-kubectl-helm
  only: [main]
  script:
    - echo "Configuring Kube..."
    - kubectl config get-contexts
 //connects to cluster, gets auth...
    - echo "Deploying Helm..."
    - echo "$DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG"
    - helm upgrade demoapp ./install/octodemo -n demoapp -f ./install/octodemo/values-prod.yaml --set image.tag=${DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG}
```

the output from the pipeline log:

```
$ echo "Deploying Helm..."
Deploying Helm...
$ echo "$DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG"
aa8905b2
$ helm upgrade demoapp ./install/octodemo -n demoapp -f ./install/octodemo/values-prod.yaml --set image.tag=${DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG}
Release "demoapp" has been upgraded. Happy Helming!
NAME: demoapp
LAST DEPLOYED: Fri Sep 22 21:59:18 2023
NAMESPACE: demoapp
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 4
NOTES:
1. Get the application URL by running these commands:
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:01
Job succeeded
```

Even can confirm from Docker Hub that the image tag has no :
[image: docker hub tags]

The deployment yaml conditionally looking for a :

```
spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Values.frontend.deploy.containers.name }}
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.frontend.deploy.containers.imagePullPolicy }}
          {{- if contains ":" .Values.image.tag}}
          image:  "{{ .Values.image.frontend }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | replace ":" "" }}"
          {{- else }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.frontend }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          {{- end }}
```

But it keeps ending up back on the cluster:

```
mycomp:~/folder$ kubectl get po --all-namespaces -o yaml | grep image: | cut -d ":" -f2,3 | sort | uniq
 :aa8905b2
```

I just don't get it, any suggestions are appreciated.